# Slow on PHP mongodb with distinct operation

Tags: php, performance, mongodb

I'm using the mongoDB to store the log of user. In my real-time report, I need to count the distinct user of the table in a specific type. In the beginning, it runs fast, but it become slower when the table becomes bigger.

Here is the code I used:

```
$connection = new MongoClient();
$result = $collection->distinct('user', array('type' => $type, 'ctime' => array('$gte' => $start)));
$total = count($result);
```

`$total` is the total number of unique user

Can anyone suggest me how to improve the query to get the better performance?
Many thanks.

Comment: Where is your document structure?
Also type your query in the shell version, this way people will be able to faster test it.

Comment: The document structure is:  array('user', 'type', 'ctime')

Comment: That's not a document structure, we mean what does your row look like, also how many rows are you distincting

Comment: sorry, I created the row by PHP and the row looks like 
{"allen", "type1", 1378375980}
{"allen", "type1", 1378375980}
{"john", "type2", 1378895340}

Comment: Is there an index on `user`? And how many rows are you distincting?

Comment: Should I need to add an index for user? There are about 20 kinds of types to distinct. The total rows are more than 1000000

Comment: An index cna make this faster, MongoDB should be able to use that instead of the actual documents, hmm 1,000,000 shouldn't be too bad to distinct but still I wouldn't expect it in some magically small amount of time

Answer (score 0):

use `$collection->ensureIndex(array('user' => 1));` to create index on user field.